# Filing a UK Company Tax return for 22/23- is it possible to bring back a trading loss from 23/24?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, accounting, small-business, business

Whilst filing my UK company tax return for the financial year covering 22/23 in the section '**Trading losses**', under '**Bring back a loss from a later period**' is states the following:

> You can only bring back a loss if both the following apply:
>
> - the loss happened between 1 Feb 2023 and 31 Jan 2024
> - you've already filed the tax return for the period when the loss happened

I'm not an accountant so realise i must be missing something, but am confused as to how both these requirements could ever be met.

Could someone please explain how it's possible to 'bring back' a loss from a subsequent year to reduce your tax liability for the previous year?

Comment: Interesting question, but this may not be the right place to ask it.  This is the *Personal Finance* forum, and your question seems to be about a Corporate Taxation issue.

Comment: Thanks Greg, i had wondered that myself as it's listed as 'personal finance and money'. But there seems to be a lot of existing business related tax/accountancy questions on here and i couldn't find a more appropriate stack exchange to ask on.